# pass array from controller to javascript in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am trying to plot a graph in codeigniter framework. I have a javascript code for plotting graph. The graph is plotting with respect to database values.

I write the php code for fetching data from the database and create a controller for read the model value. but i don't know how to to sent that fetched value in the controller to the javascript in codeigniter framework. here i am attaching the controller code.

```
$this->load->model('piechart');
        $res['h'] = $this->piechart->piechart();
```

$res containing the value of graph.

Comment: Can you post your code. view side and controller. also the js part too

Comment: View part is attaching below <div class="chart-container">
                            <canvas id="pigraph"></canvas>
                        </div> <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/pages/pidiagram.js"></script>

Comment: Model- class piechart extends CI_Model
{
    public  function piechart()
    {
            $this->db->select('City');
            $this->db->from($this->tbl_hotel);
            $this->db->order_by("City", "asc");
            $query = $this->db->get(); 
            $result= $query->result(); return $result;
    }
}

Comment: Js- $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "Welcome/pidiagram",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            //alert(data);
            console.log(data);}});});

Comment: i fetched value from model and set to controller . then i want to pass that value from controller to js. js have the role for plotting graph in the particular canvas id

Comment: please anyone help me

Comment: in your controller just do this:  echo json_encode($res);

Comment: that will direct to the js file?

Comment: there must be a function to display the piechart,we need to call a function in pidiagram.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: Thank you so much for your support.